# DIV jumps to odd position

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand why

In the 4th DIV in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WarrickF/884Q9/

I've used the following for content:

```
<div class="xxx1">xxx</div><div class="xxx2">yyy</div>
```

Why does this DIV no longer line up with the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` can have a funny effect if it doesn't have any content. It has to do with the `vertical-align` property.

With no content (or in this case floated content) in an inline-block div, it seems to assume it's an image and vertical-align defaults to `vertical-align: baseline;` instead of `vertical-align: bottom;` which is the default for an inline-block element with text content.

You can easily fix this by adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to the player class.